# Unexpected line-break behaviour / text alignment issue

Tags: php, html, css

I have some divs on a page that are around 300px wide. The text inside them is line breaking incorrectly. The text appears something like below (this is one single block of text, there are no explicit line breaks):

```
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,                         |
| consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc magna enim,       |
| hendrerit vitae                                     |
| viverra non, consectetur at enim. Donec             |
| ut nisi convallis nunc pharetra tempus vel ac urna. |
```

Hopefully you can see how this isn't how the text should appear. Each line should run as close to the end of each div as possible. The html in each div is in the following structure:

```
<div class="item">
  <h3>Lorem</h3>
  <div>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <span class="blah">dolor sit</span>
    <span class="blahblah">amet, consectetur adipiscing (etc.)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are various spans and what not in there, but there is no logical relationship between the generated line breaks and html source as far as I can see. By that I mean, the line breaks do not occur at each span or anything. The spans remain inline. The h3 is floated left.

This html is dynamically generated by php. I think this must be the problem because, as a test, I copied the source code (from the browser's view source option), pasted it into a new .html file, saved it and viewed that in the browser and the line-breaks etc. appeared how I want them to. I don't really understand how this could be. The source code generated by php is exactly the same as in this test I have done, yet one renders correctly while the other does not. The text is coming from a MySQL database. Could it be some encoding issue?

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks.

### EDIT: Source Code Requested

This is displaying correctly, it is the generated php version of this source code (which is identical as far as I can tell) which is not correct.

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css">

            * {padding: 0;margin: 0;}
            a {text-decoration: none;}
            ul {list-style: none;}  
            body, input {font-family: Georgia;font-size: 15px;}
            body {color: #444;background-color: #d9d9d9;}

            .item {
                width: 296px;
                margin-bottom: 14px;
            }

            .item div {
                background-color: #d1d1d1;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }


            .item div span:first-child {
                margin: 0px 8px;
                font-style: italic;
            }

            .item h3 {
                font-size: 18px;
                color: #444;
                margin-left: -8px;
                font-weight: bold;
                float: left;
                line-height: 16px;
            }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="dictionary">       

        <div class="item">
            <h3 id="w4">[ ... ]</h3>
            <div>
                <span>n</span>
                <span class="number">1.</span>
                <span class="definition">A band worn around the waist to hold clothing to one's body (usually pants), hold weapons (such as a gun or sword), or serve as a decorative piece of clothing.</span>
                <span class="number">2.</span>
                <span class="definition">A band that is used in a machine to help transfer motion or power.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <h3 id="w5">[ ... ]</h3>
            <div>
                <span>n</span>
                <span class="number">1.</span>
                <span class="definition">A (usually self-sustaining) chemical reaction involving the bonding of oxygen with carbon or other fuel, with the production of heat and the presence offlame or smouldering.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <h3 id="w6">[ ... ]</h3>
            <div>
                <span>n</span>
                <span class="number">1.</span>
                <span class="definition">A covering for the head, often in the approximate form of a cone or a cylinder closed at its top end, and sometimes having a brim and otherdecoration.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual example with the source from the browser and the applicable css?

Comment: Open the page source in a text editor that displays hidden characters, you might notice a tab or a control character.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I've added the source code.

Comment: You are supposed to post minimal code that demonstrates the problem. Posting non-problem code does not help. And “generated php version” does not make sense; HTML markup does not generate PHP code, it may be generated by PHP code.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry. I didn't think I had posted too much code. I removed some irrelevant parts in my last edit. I have in effect posted both the non-problem and problem code since they are the same. It is just the "static" version that displays correctly while the "dynamic" version does not. And I know html markup does not generate php. By "generated php version" I meant the html produced by php.

Comment: My guess would be the Content-Type text encoding is causing whitespace in the html to be parsed.  What happens if you put your tags on one line in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Possible culprit after seeing your CSS: `float: left;` on `.item h3`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately removing `float: left` does not fix the problem.